# Split PHP and HTML tags and marge it together in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html, regex

I am working on extension in JavaScript for Text Editor. Now i working on Code Formator. But i found one thing i cant solve. If you use PHP and HTML together like this:

```
<?php
    Some php
    Some php
    Some php
    ?>
    <body>
      <head></head>
      <anotherTag></anotherTag>
    </body>
```

I have that code like String in `Javascript`. Now I must separate PHP and HTML, use on in Format separate. After it i must Marge it again to return it to Editor. Any ideas, for example with regex or something? :) Thanks.

Comment: I just want to let you know that although it sounds as the best solution at the moment in javascript to parse a string and capture parts of it, it is a bad practise to use regex on HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in many ways. The general solution is to search in your string for opening/closing tags and then slice that part of string and put it in variable or array that you like to work with. and then simply merge the strings.

This is a list of JavaScript methods with examples that may help you through this:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_string_methods.asp

Answer (score 0):

This way you can catch the HTML and PHP code, but it will only catch it correctly if there only is one PHP statement:

```
~
(.*?) #catches HTML in the start
(?:<[?]php) #looks for opening php tag but doesn't capture it
(.*?) #catches all php code
(?:[?]>) #looks for php ending tag but doesn't capture it
(.*) #catches HTML afterwards
~xs
```